# Solr on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, solr, solrnet

I need to install Solr on Windows Server 2008 R2, and integrate it with a asp.net mvc3 application. I have tried to find the docs on how to install/setup solr on windows server, but found no good docs / help. Moreover, after install I want to integrate results into asp.net mvc3 applications, so a search query and results need to be displayed there. I'm also clue less how to do this. Although both the questions are little different, any suggestions / document that may help us getting started are truly welcome.

Comment: I would suggest that you install it using [**Bitami** stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/solr)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the step by step procedure to get you started:

**Step 1:** Download Solr. It's just a zip file.

**Step 2:** Copy from your `SOLR_HOME_DIR/dist/apache-solr-1.3.0.war` to your tomcat webapps directory: `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/solr.war` – Note the war file name change. That’s important.

**Step 3:** Create your solr home directory at a location of your choosing. This is where the configuration for that solr install resides. The easiest way to do this is to copy the `SOLR_HOME_DIR/examples/solr` directory to wherever it is you want your solr home container to be. Say place it in `C:\solr`.

**Step 4:** Hope you have set your environment variables, if not then please set `JAVA_HOME`, `JRE_HOME`, `CATALINA_OPTS`, `CATALINA_HOME`. Note that `CATALINA_HOME` refers to your Tomcat directory & `CATALINA_OPTS` refers to the amount of heap memory you want to give to your Solr.

**Step 5:** Start tomcat. Note this is only necessary to allow tomcat to unpack your war file. If you look under `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps` there should now be a solr directory.

**Step 6:** Stop tomcat

**Step 7:** Go into that solr directory and edit `WEB-INF/web.xml`. Scroll down until you see an entry that looks like this:

```
<!-- People who want to hardcode their "Solr Home" directly into the 
     WAR File can set the JNDI property here... 
 --> 
<!-- 
  <env-entry> 
     <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name> 
     <env-entry-value>/Path/To/My/solr/Home/solr/</env-entry-value> 
     <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type> 
  </env-entry> 
-->
```

Set your Solr home (for example: `C:\solr`) and uncomment the env entry.

**Step 8:** Start Tomcat again, and things should be going splendidly. You should be able to verify that solr is running by trying the url `http://localhost:8080/solr/admin/`.

The other answers here are good enough to get you integrate Solr with your ASP.Net & it should be pretty simple as Solr exposes HTTP.

Comment: thank you for this detailed answer, I'll be doing it tomorrow... will post here if face any issues...

Comment: Just an update that it worked great.. and I was able to install it without any issues. Thanks Yavar for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

installing on windows means:

- donwloading zip from apache
- unzipping to the dir you desire

that's all, now you have to define you schema.xml, solrconfig.xml etc, start with the [solr tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/doc-files/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat application server can host your solr instances.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#Multiple_Solr_apps

Put in an XML file (given in that page) `/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/Catalina/localhost` to register the Solr app and
in `conf/solrconfig.xml` set the index directory
`<dataDir>${solr.data.dir:/var/www/app/app_indexer}</dataDir>`. Sorry for the Linux paths...

As for a .Net library, SolrNet is discussed here on StackOverflow often.

Answer (score 0):

To install Solr simply install 64-bit version of Tomcat and deploy Solr war file. 
To incorporate Solr (request and result pages) into my asp.net app I used [AJAX Solr](https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr/wiki/reuters-tutorial).

[Here](http://evolvingweb.github.com/ajax-solr/examples/reuters/index.html) is a demo of how it may look like.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good article on this site which offers solr integration plugin for nopcommerce. They have a very good support and documentation here that might be helpful to you:

http://www.nopaccelerate.com/wiki/installing-apache-solr/

and

http://www.nopaccelerate.com/wiki/configuring-apache-solr-to-use-with-nopaccelerate/

Thanks, all the best.